# Phpmailer from address failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, zoho

I currently have my site hosted on freehostia, which doesn't allow SMTP.  As a work around for this I created an account at Zoho (www.zoho.com) which lets you link your domain to their server and send and receive email through them.
I have also installed phpmailer on my host as instructed.

I have created a test file using the smtp information given by Zoho, and as far as I can tell everything is set up correctly.
The problem is that when I try to send mail I get the error:
**Mailer Error: The following From address failed: donotreply@domain.com : Called Mail() without being connected**

The code I have for my test file looks like this:

```
<?php
require '../PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

$mail->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";

$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = "donotreply@domain.com";

$mail->Password = "mypassword";

$mail->From = "donotreply@domain.com";

$mail->FromName = "Domain";

$mail->AddAddress("testaddress@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = "Test with PHPMailer";

$mail->Body = "This is a sample body text!";

$mail->IsHTML (true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try replacing your Username and From from donotreply@domain.com to donotreply@your_domain.com or donotreply@zoho.com

Comment: No luck on swapping it out for @zoho.com.  Is it possible that the hosts inability to send smtp is still the source of the problem here?

Comment: echo `$mail->IsSMTP();` and check what it prints. I  guess it is the check whether SMTP exists or not, and host's inability to send SMTP may be a problem, you may try configuring your php.ini on the host too.

Comment: This statement returned no:    `if ($mail->IsSMTP())
 echo "yes";
else
 echo "no";`  So I'm thinking it must not...  Is that something you think I can change, or am I stuck with it?

Comment: What I suggest is, configure your .ini file (I guess you're working on Apache server) and set the SMTP settings there and add the server of the SMTP server to the zoho server. Hope that helps!

Comment: The only thing I could find in the .ini file was: `For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25`  Changing that to smtp.zoho.com and port 465 didn't have any effect, so it's looking like it might not be possible...

Comment: Now again check with IsSMTP();

Comment: It still says no.  The complete the lines after that in the .ini file also say: `; For Win32 only.
SMTP = locahost
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = 
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =`  After changing the smtp and smtp_port I set sendmail_from to donotreply@domain.com but still nothing changed.

Comment: No idea then. I was just trying, I don't have much knowledge of it. Please post if you get the answer sometime, and re-post the question of start a bounty. Hope that'll help to get some better person to answer your query.

Comment: One thing, a `;` in front of a line makes it a comment in php.ini. Remove that `;` and then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the free plan through freehostia doesn't allow any outgoing connections, so trying to contact any outside mail server would have been impossible. 
Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of digging to figure out the CentOS 7 disables SMTP connections by default.

Try running these lines if you run into this " Mailer Error: The following From address failed: " and "Called Mail() without being connected."

sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Thanks to the following web article:

https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix